# Discord JS : Display several modals with one interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I create a discord bot that when a user enters the /play command displays a modal (thanks to [discord-modals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-modals)). 
On this one there is a question with necessarily an input to answer it. 
If the answer is wrong the interaction returns a message (it works perfectly).
If the answer is correct, a second modal is displayed directly with another question.

However, it is impossible to display the second modal if the answer to the first question is correct.

So here is my code:

```js
// Importing Modals and Text Inputs
const { Modal, showModal, TextInputComponent } = require("discord-modals");

module.exports = {
    command: "play",
    name: "Play",
    description: "Start the game",
    category: "event",
    slash: true,

    callback: async ({ user, interaction, client }) => {

// The list of questions and answers that will be displayed in the modals
        questions = { [0]: "What is the name of the event ?", [1]: "How are you", [2]: "Who am I ?", [3]: "What's your country ?", [4]: "What's our group's name ?", [5]: "5 + 5 = ?", [6]: "3 + 3 = ?" };
        answers = { [0]: "joker event", [1]: "fine", [2]: "joker", [3]: "france", [4]: "partouche", [5]: "10", [6]: "6" };

// A simple function that will display the questions randomly
        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        }
    
        var rand1 = getRandomInt(5);
        var rand2 = getRandomInt(5);

// My two modals
        const modal = new Modal()
            .setCustomId(`modal_1`)
            .setTitle(`Question 1`)
            .addComponents(new TextInputComponent().setCustomId(`input_1`).setLabel(`${questions[rand1]}`).setStyle("SHORT").setPlaceholder("Write your answer").setRequired(true));

        const modal2 = new Modal()
            .setCustomId(`modal_2`)
            .setTitle(`Question 2`)
            .addComponents(new TextInputComponent().setCustomId(`input_2`).setLabel(`${questions[rand2]}`).setStyle("SHORT").setPlaceholder("Write your answer").setRequired(true));


// A function that displays the modal and when answering, compares the answer entered by the user with the answer to the question

        function showModals(actualModal) {
            showModal(actualModal, {
                client: client,
                interaction: interaction,
            });

            client.on("modalSubmit", async (modal_answered) => {
                if (modal_answered.customId === `modal_1`) {
                    var answer = modal_answered.getTextInputValue(`input_1`);
                    if (answer.toLowerCase() == answers[rand1].toLowerCase()) {
                        await modal_answered.reply({
                            content: showModals(modal2),
                            ephemeral: true,
                        });
                    } else {
                        return await modal_answered.reply({
                            content: `Sorry ${interaction.user}, you have answered incorrectly.`,
                            ephemeral: true,
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (modal_answered.customId === `modal_2`) {
                    var answer = modal_answered.getTextInputValue(`input_2`);
                    if (answer.toLowerCase() == answers[rand2].toLowerCase()) {
                        await modal_answered.reply({
                            content: 'You won !',
                            ephemeral: true,
                        });
                    } else {
                        return await modal_answered.reply({
                            content: `Sorry ${interaction.user}, you have answered incorrectly.`,
                            ephemeral: true,
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        showModals(modal);
    },
};
```

I then have two errors that I can't correct:

```
An error occurred when showing a modal. DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
```

and

```
Uncaught DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

Thank you for your help, if you have any questions don't hesitate